# from xgboost import XGBClassifier & import xgboost as xgb

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost

I have already installed xgboost (using pip on anaconda),and `import xgboost as xgb` is fine.However when I am using `from xgboost import XGBClassifier` ，there is an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'XGBClassifier'

information for platform:

```
1.windows 7

2.(base) C:\Users\george>pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can us
e --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.con
f under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
alabaster (0.7.10)
anaconda-client (1.6.9)
anaconda-navigator (1.7.0)
anaconda-project (0.8.2)
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
astroid (1.6.1)
astropy (2.0.3)
attrs (17.4.0)
Babel (2.5.3)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)
bitarray (0.8.1)
bkcharts (0.2)
blaze (0.11.3)
bleach (2.1.2)
bokeh (0.12.13)
boto (2.48.0)
boto3 (1.9.42)
botocore (1.12.42)
Bottleneck (1.2.1)
certifi (2018.1.18)
cffi (1.11.4)
chardet (3.0.4)
click (6.7)
cloudpickle (0.5.2)
clyent (1.2.2)
colorama (0.3.9)
comtypes (1.1.4)
conda (4.4.10)
conda-build (3.4.1)
conda-verify (2.0.0)
contextlib2 (0.5.5)
cryptography (2.1.4)
cycler (0.10.0)
Cython (0.27.3)
cytoolz (0.9.0)
dask (0.20.1)
datashape (0.5.4)
decorator (4.2.1)
distributed (1.24.1)
docutils (0.14)
entrypoints (0.2.3)
et-xmlfile (1.0.1)
fastcache (1.0.2)
featuretools (0.4.0)
filelock (2.0.13)
Flask (0.12.2)
Flask-Cors (3.0.3)
future (0.17.1)
gevent (1.2.2)
glob2 (0.6)
greenlet (0.4.12)
h5py (2.7.1)
heapdict (1.0.0)
html5lib (1.0.1)
idna (2.6)
imageio (2.2.0)
imagesize (0.7.1)
ipython (6.2.1)
ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
ipywidgets (7.1.1)
isort (4.2.15)
itsdangerous (0.24)
jdcal (1.3)
jedi (0.11.1)
Jinja2 (2.10)
jmespath (0.9.3)
jsonschema (2.6.0)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (5.2.2)
jupyter-console (5.2.0)
jupyter-core (4.4.0)
jupyterlab (0.31.4)
jupyterlab-launcher (0.10.2)
lazy-object-proxy (1.3.1)
llvmlite (0.21.0)
locket (0.2.0)
lxml (4.1.1)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
matplotlib (2.1.2)
mccabe (0.6.1)
menuinst (1.4.11)
mistune (0.8.3)
mpmath (1.0.0)
msgpack (0.5.6)
msgpack-python (0.5.1)
multipledispatch (0.4.9)
navigator-updater (0.1.0)
nbconvert (5.3.1)
nbformat (4.4.0)
networkx (2.1)
nltk (3.2.5)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (5.4.0)
numba (0.36.2)
numexpr (2.6.4)
numpy (1.14.0)
numpydoc (0.7.0)
odo (0.5.1)
olefile (0.45.1)
openpyxl (2.4.10)
packaging (16.8)
pandas (0.23.4)
pandocfilters (1.4.2)
parso (0.1.1)
partd (0.3.8)
path.py (10.5)
pathlib2 (2.3.0)
patsy (0.5.0)
pep8 (1.7.1)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
Pillow (5.0.0)
pip (9.0.3)
pkginfo (1.4.1)
plotly (3.4.2)
pluggy (0.6.0)
ply (3.10)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.15)
psutil (5.4.8)
py (1.5.2)
pycodestyle (2.3.1)
pycosat (0.6.3)
pycparser (2.18)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycurl (7.43.0.1)
pyflakes (1.6.0)
Pygments (2.2.0)
pylint (1.8.2)
pyodbc (4.0.22)
pyOpenSSL (17.5.0)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
PySocks (1.6.7)
pytest (3.3.2)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2017.3)
PyWavelets (0.5.2)
pywin32 (222)
pywinpty (0.5)
PyYAML (3.12)
pyzmq (17.1.2)
QtAwesome (0.4.4)
qtconsole (4.3.1)
QtPy (1.3.1)
requests (2.18.4)
retrying (1.3.3)
rope (0.10.7)
ruamel-yaml (0.15.35)
s3fs (0.1.6)
s3transfer (0.1.13)
scikit-image (0.13.1)
scikit-learn (0.19.1)
scipy (1.0.0)
seaborn (0.8.1)
Send2Trash (1.4.2)
setuptools (38.4.0)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
six (1.11.0)
snowballstemmer (1.2.1)
sortedcollections (0.5.3)
sortedcontainers (1.5.9)
Sphinx (1.6.6)
sphinxcontrib-websupport (1.0.1)
spyder (3.2.6)
SQLAlchemy (1.2.1)
statsmodels (0.8.0)
sympy (1.1.1)
tables (3.4.2)
tblib (1.3.2)
terminado (0.8.1)
testpath (0.3.1)
toolz (0.9.0)
tornado (5.1.1)
tqdm (4.28.1)
traitlets (4.3.2)
typing (3.6.2)
unicodecsv (0.14.1)
urllib3 (1.22)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
webencodings (0.5.1)
Werkzeug (0.14.1)
wheel (0.30.0)
widgetsnbextension (3.1.0)
win-inet-pton (1.0.1)
win-unicode-console (0.5)
wincertstore (0.2)
wrapt (1.10.11)
xgboost (0.81)
xlrd (1.1.0)
XlsxWriter (1.0.2)
xlwings (0.11.5)
xlwt (1.3.0)
zict (0.1.3)
```

Anyone has any ideas how to fix this?I have read some information which recommend to update xcode(it supposed to be used on Mac) and some recommed alter the name of xgboost.py to another(no sight of this file)

Anyone knows please kindly give some advice.

Comment: This is what I used to get xgboost working: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en

Comment: The key part for me was defining this: `MINGW_PATH = 'C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin'` and then changing my path: `os.environ['PATH'] = MINGW_PATH + ';' + os.environ['PATH']`

Comment: After you `import xgboost as xgb`, what shows up when you do `dir(xgb)`?

Comment: @JacobIRR ['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Comment: should have lots more in there. Take a look at the article I linked and try using that method.

Comment: I don't know if you installed xgboost the same way as I did, but if not, I installed it on windows using this package rather than the one in conda forge or with pip : 
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
It worked fine for me

Comment: It seems  XGB is not installed properly. Refer @ https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html and install again.